# How to make a QML toggle button that tracks/controls any boolean property

Tags: qt, binding, qml, qtquick2

My QML/QtQuick exercise for today is to make a little ToggleButton widget that I can instantiate to monitor the state of a specified boolean QML property, and that also toggles that property's state when I click on the ToggleButton.

So far I have this for my ToggleButton component:

```
// Contents of ToggleButton.qml
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

Button {
    property bool isActive: false

    onClicked: {
        isActive = !isActive;
    }

    style: ButtonStyle {
        background: Rectangle {
            border.width: control.activeFocus ? 2 : 1
            border.color: "black"
            radius: 4
            color:  isActive ? "red" : "gray";
        }
    }
}
```

.... and here is my little test harness that I use to see whether it works the way I want it to, or not:

```
// Contents of main.qml
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
   visible: true
   width: 360
   height: 360

   Rectangle {
      property bool lighten: false;

      id:blueRect
      x: 32; y:32; width:64; height:64
      color: lighten ? "lightBlue" : "blue";

      MouseArea {
         anchors.fill: parent
         onClicked:    parent.lighten = !parent.lighten;
      }
   }

   Rectangle {
      property bool lighten: false;

      id:greenRect
      x:192; y:32; width:64; height:64
      color: lighten ? "lightGreen" : "green";

      MouseArea {
         anchors.fill: parent
         onClicked:    parent.lighten = !parent.lighten;
      }
   }

   ToggleButton {
      x:32; y:128
      text: "Bright Blue Rect"
      isActive: blueRect.lighten
   }

   ToggleButton {
      x:192; y:128
      text: "Bright Green Rect"
      isActive: greenRect.lighten
   }
}
```

You can run this by saving the code to ToggleButton.qml and main.qml (respectively) and then running "qmlscene main.qml".

Note that if you click on the blue or green rectangles, it works as expected; the boolean "lighten" property of the Rectangle object is toggled on and off, causing the Rectangle to change color, and the associated ToggleButton also reacts appropriately (by turning itself red when the "lighten" property is true, and gray when the "lighten" property is false).

So far, so good, but if you then click on the ToggleButton itself, the binding is broken:  that is, clicking on the ToggleButton causes the ToggleButton to turn red/gray as expected, but the rectangle's color doesn't follow suit, and after doing that, clicking on the rectangle no longer causes the ToggleButton's state to change, either.

My question is, what is the trick to doing this properly, so that I always have a bidirectional correspondence between the ToggleButton and the property it is tracking?  (Note that the ideal solution would add as little code as possible to main.qml, since I'd like this functionality to be encapsulated inside ToggleButton.qml, to minimize the amount of complexity exposed to the rest of my QML app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like one way to solve this problem is to have the ToggleButton declare its state using an alias-property, rather than a regular property.  That way there is only the one external property (since the ToggleButton's internal property is really just an alias to the external one), and therefore no bidirectional binding is necessary.  Here's an updated version of the QML code that works as expected:

ToggleButton.qml:

```
// Contents of ToggleButton.qml
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

Button {
    onClicked: {
        isActive = !isActive;
    }

    style: ButtonStyle {
        background: Rectangle {
            border.width: control.activeFocus ? 2 : 1
            border.color: "black"
            radius: 4
            color:  isActive ? "red" : "gray";
        }
    }    
}
```

main.qml:

```
// Contents of main.qml
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
   visible: true
   width: 360
   height: 360

   Rectangle {
      property bool lighten: false;

      id:blueRect
      x: 32; y:32; width:64; height:64
      color: lighten ? "lightBlue" : "blue";

      MouseArea {
         anchors.fill: parent
         onClicked:    parent.lighten = !parent.lighten;
      }
   }

   Rectangle {
      property bool lighten: false;

      id:greenRect
      x:192; y:32; width:64; height:64
      color: lighten ? "lightGreen" : "green";

      MouseArea {
         anchors.fill: parent
         onClicked:    parent.lighten = !parent.lighten;
      }
   }

   ToggleButton {
      x:32; y:128
      text: "Bright Blue Rect"
      property alias isActive: blueRect.lighten
   }

   ToggleButton {
      x:192; y:128
      text: "Bright Green Rect"
      property alias isActive: greenRect.lighten
   }
}
```

Comment: Interesting use of a property alias! I had not seen that used before like this. So far, I have only seen them used to expose internal properties of a component to its API surface. There is a design problem though: your ToggleButton now relies on something from the scope it is used from. If you forget the property alias in the component use, QML would try to find it in any parent scope. That could lead to rather suprising bugs. There is also no hint for the user of your component that he has to add that isActive alias property himself, instead of just setting a value as he will be expecting.

Answer (score 5):

The reason this does not work is that you are overwriting the binding with a fixed value. By manually assigning a value in you `onClicked` you overwrite the binding with a value.

The problem is: QML does not support 2way bindings right now. There are, however, some tricks to create one. See http://imaginativethinking.ca/bi-directional-data-binding-qt-quick/

Note: Instead of using the `isActive` property like this, why not use the checked state of the button? (From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-button.html)) This way the binding won't break, even if you click the button:

```
// Contents of ToggleButton.qml
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

Button {
    //use the "checked" property instead of your own "isActive"

    checkable: true

    style: ButtonStyle {
        background: Rectangle {
            border.width: control.activeFocus ? 2 : 1
            border.color: "black"
            radius: 4
            color:  checked? "red" : "gray";
        }
    }
}
```